# After converting a CFG to a PDA, what is an example input string to the PDA?

Tags: automata, finite-automata

For example, the following CFG:

S$\rightarrow$aSb|$\epsilon$

A valid string within the language described by the CFG would be, e.g., "aabb".

The converted PDA has the following form:

[image]

The loop transitions on $q_2$ are:

1. $\epsilon,S{\rightarrow}aSb$
2. $\epsilon,S{\rightarrow}\epsilon$
3. $a,a{\rightarrow}\epsilon$
4. $b,b{\rightarrow}\epsilon$

Given this newly generated PDA, what is an example input string that it accepts? What is the PDA's alphabet?

**EDIT**:
What's keeping me from answering this by myself? Well, the described CFG outputs strings such as "aabb". I could build a PDA which would determine if a string matched the form $aabb$. For example:

$\qquad$ Add a \$ to the stack. Then, for each $a$, add an $a$ to the stack. Then, take an epsilon move to another state which reads $b$ from the input and pops $a$ from the stack. Then, move to an accept state if the \$ symbol is left on the stack and accept if the input is also empty.

However, the converted PDA (from the original CFG) does not appear to take the same type of input as the one that I just described. There are e.g. variables ($S$) in the input, whereas the non-converted PDA accepts only $a$s and $b$s. Why?

**EDIT 2**:
Disclaimer: I came up with this question on my own. The image is a screenshot from a slide deck showing an example of a CFG-to-PDA conversion process.

**EDIT 3**:
The procedure of converting a CFG to a PDA is taken from Sipser.

Comment: I came up with this question by myself. The question is related to a problem found in a slide deck. However, the question of what input strings are passed to this type of PDA is solely mine and mine alone!

Comment: Disclaimer (@reinierpost): I came up with this question by myself.

Comment: What's keeping me from answering it myself? Well, the CFG for the problem outputs strings such as "aabb". I could build a PDA which would determine if a string matched the form "aabb". However, the converted PDA (from the original CFG) does not appear to take the same type of input. There are e.g. variables ($S$) in the input. Why?

Comment: If the transitions on $q_2$ are what you say, then your PDA can only recognize the empty word, since each transition takes $\varepsilon$ as input and only modifies the stack.

Comment: Sorry, @Nathaniel, there were 2 missing transitions in the loop, namely, those for the terminals $a$ and $b$.